# MVC: Where is the right place to set error messages?

Tags: c#, mvc, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ASP.NET MVC application where in all my Models have an Errors Property used to store non-validation errors which I than display in my Views. Where is the right place to populate the error list according to MVC? Inside the model or inside the controller?

First Option

```
public class MyModel
{
 public DataOperationResult DoSomething()
  {
   //do something with data
   if (result != DataOperation.Success)
   {
     Errors.Add("Something went wrong");
   }
   return result;       
 }
}
```

Second option

```
 public class MyController
  {
   public ActionResult DoSomething()
    {
     MyModel model = new myModel();
     DataOperationResult result = model.DoSomething();
     if (result != DataOperation.Success)
     {
      model.Errors.Add("Something went wrong");
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are the errors occurring inside the model, or in the controller?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Mostly the errors are occurring in the model, different DataOperationResults are defined for different error types and depending on the error type the controller redirects to different pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don`t think storing error in models is good idea. Models are responsible for storing data not data and error. You breaking single responsibility principle. You should store erroros in ViewModels and populate them in controller.